# Cannot send ALPN request to APNS with python 3.5 and Hyper

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, pyopenssl, hyper, alpn

I am trying to implement APNS service on my Python REST server with [Hyper](https://github.com/zeit/hyper). 
Since APNS now require HTTP/2 (ALPN) protocol, I was not able to `get_response()` from Hyper connection. It throws the below error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 41, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 187, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 185, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/dist-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 58, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/dist-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 68, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 489, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 449, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 486, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/rest_framework/decorators.py", line 52, in handler
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/vr-inspire/apns/views.py", line 137, in apns
    resp = conn.get_response()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/hyper/common/connection.py", line 129, in get_response
    return self._conn.get_response(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/hyper/http11/connection.py", line 203, in get_response
    self._sock.fill()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/hyper/common/bufsocket.py", line 169, in fill
    raise ConnectionResetError()
ConnectionResetError
```

I did some research, and it turns out ALPN require OpenSSL 1.0.2. I compiled OpenSSL 1.0.2i and Python 3.5.1 from source with reference to [this](https://tuannvm.github.io/blogs/how-to-compile-python-with-custom-openssl-version/) article.

I checked the ssl version with `import ssl print(ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION)` and returns `OpenSSL 1.0.2i  22 Sep 2016`. But `ssl.HAS_ALPN` return **False**.

I am using Amazon Linux, how may I use ALPN to send Request to APNS server? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I try to use python 3.6.1 with openssl 1.0.2k and it works.